# Ember - child component updating a property coming from query params via parent component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember 1.13.0 and trying to update a property coming from query params in a child component.

In child component js, when "time" is not defined, I am setting it to 1200. If i log the value of "time" (*this.get('time')*) in child  component, after i update it, i can see its value being updated. But its doesn't get through to parent component action.

So, why I am not able to get its value in parent, if its getting updated in child?

**Top level** component:

```
{{parent-component time = model.params.incomingTime}}
```

**Parent** component:

```
<div>hello</hello>
{{child-component time=time}}
```

**Parent** component JS:

```
actions: {
 submit:function(){
  var t = this.get('time')
 }
}
```

**Child** component:

```
<div>Time is {{currentTime}}</div>
```

**Child** component JS:

```
currentTime: function(){
 if(this.get('time')){
  return time;
 } else {
    this.set('time','1200');
    return '1200'
 }
}.property()
```

**Top** level route:

```
var route = Ember.Route.extend({
 queryParams: {
  time: {refreshModel:true, replace: false}
 },
 model: function(params){
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({ params: params})
 },
 setupController: function(controller, model) {
            controller.set('model', model);
        }
})
```

Comment: show us route model hook ?

Comment: Added the hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by declaring new CP in parent component and returning simply "time" from that. Now I am passing that CP to child and then updating it via action in parent. This way it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Will `incomingTime` property comes in `params` if so your code will work. or else it will fail.

```
{{parent-component time=model.params.incomingTime}}
```

**Update1**:
sending entire `model.params` might work.

Top level component:

```
{{parent-component modelParams=model.params}}
```

Parent component:

```
<div>hello</hello>
{{child-component modelParams=modelParams}}
```

Parent component JS:

```
actions: {
 submit:function(){
  var t = this.get('modelParams.time')
 }
}
```

Child component:

```
<div>Time is {{currentTime}}</div>
```

Child component JS:

```
currentTime: function(){
 if(this.get('modelParams.time')){
  return time;
 } else {
    this.set('modelParams.time','1200');
    return '1200'
 }
}.property()
```

Comment: Well, if there is value, i am simply returning it in child component, otherwise only i need to set time, and thats where i cant access it in parent component

Comment: if `model.params.incomingTime` property is `undefined` then ember cant propagate your childComponent changes to parentComponent. so I will encourage you to have  default value for `model.params.incomingTime`. otherwise move defaultValue logic to inside model hook or in corresponsing controller.

Comment: or else you can send `model.params` itself and you can use `this.get('model.params.time')` to get the property and to set you can say `this.set('model.params.time','value')`

Comment: Well, I am a little reluctant to send the whole params down. Why would there be a need for that. You know, I upgraded Ember 1.11 to 1.13. And I faced this issue. The existing code worked with 1.11 but not 1.13.  May be i was thinking to probably define time at parent level and pass it down. But I am not sure if there's a need to pass down whole params.

Comment: I can however try that having default value for incomingTime as you suggested. Let me do that and see what happens.

Comment: I got it working by declaring new CP in parent component and returning simply "time" from that. Now I am passing that CP to child and then updating it via action in parent. This way it seems to work.